# custom username validation in wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have a wcf service and client,and would like to provide additional protection with checking of username and password. I have following validatir class

```
public class UserCredentialsValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(userName, Config.Login, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                && !String.Equals(password, Config.Password))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Invalid user credentials. Access denied.");
            }
        }
    }
```

and following server configuration

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>   <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="FileStorage.Core.ServiceModel.UserCredentialsValidator, FileStorage.Core"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="FileStorage.Core.ServiceModel.FileStorageService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" contract="FileStorage.IFileStorage" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingConfig"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="bindingConfig" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600"
                        maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="1024"/> <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Problem is that CustomValidatir never execute Validate method, e.g. validation logic doesn't execute

What can cause this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 'security' section to read this...

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

The security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" is ok. Not sure why we need transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"...

I am using transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" in my windows service hosted WCF..working fine..It seems the trick actually lies in choosing the correct security mode.